# NSIS - Reading multiple command line arguments

Tags: nsis

When passing a single argument to my windows installer,

```
MyApplication.exe CLIENT="Your Mom"
```

I can correctly read it using [GetParameters](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Get_command_line_parameters) and [GetOptions](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/GetOptions), like so:

```
${GetParameters} $0
${GetOptions} "$0" "CLIENT=" $CLIENT
```

But as soon as I attempt to pass multiple parameters

```
MyApplication.exe CLIENT="Your Mom" NAME="Jill" LOCATION="Da Yard" TEL="0221456789"
```

and try to read it like so

```
${GetParameters} $0
${GetOptions} "$0" "CLIENT=" $CLIENT 
${GetOptions} "$0" "NAME=" $NAME 
${GetOptions} "$0" "LOCATION=" $LOCATION 
${GetOptions} "$0" "TEL=" $TEL
```

The values of `$CLIENT`, `$NAME` and `$TEL` would be correct, but `$LOCATION` will contain

```
Da Yard TEL=0221456789
```

The same happens if I add more parameters, the first two and last one is always correct, but the parameters in between always contains some substring of the string passed to the installer.

Am I using `GetOptions` correctly?

Comment: I'm seeing the same bug, I will investigate and report back if I can come up with a workaround...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you change all the parameters so they start with `/` then it works for some reason! (*MyApplication.exe /CLIENT="Your Mom" /NAME="Jill" /LOCATION="Da Yard" /TEL="0221456789"* and `${GetOptions} "$0" "/LOCATION=" $LOCATION`)

If you cannot live with the / switch prefix then you would have to rewrite ${GetOptions} yourself or wait until the next NSIS release where it will hopefully be fixed.

If you want to take a stab at fixing it yourself then it would look something like this:

```
!include FileFunc.nsh

!macroundef GetOptionsBody

!macro GetOptionsBody _FILEFUNC_S
Exch $1 ; Prefix
Exch
Exch $0 ; String
Exch
ClearErrors

; Parse $0 here and look for $1 and store the suffix in $0...


FileFunc_GetOptions${_FILEFUNC_S}_notfound:
    SetErrors
    StrCpy $0 ''

FileFunc_GetOptions${_FILEFUNC_S}_end:

Pop $1
Exch $0
!macroend
```

**Edit:**

It seems like this might be by design, the help file contains this little broken English tidbit:

> First option symbol it is delimiter

**Edit2:**

I made a new GetOptions from scratch, it only supports double quotes and is probably different in all sorts of ways. I did not test much but it seems to work OK:

```
Outfile "Test.exe"
RequestExecutionLevel user
ShowInstDetails show

!include FileFunc.nsh

!if '${NSIS_PACKEDVERSION}' <= 0x0300003f ; Older versions don't support !macroundef
!define GetOptionsBody_Alt GetOptionsBody_Alt
!undef GetOptions
!define GetOptions `!insertmacro GetOptionsCall_Alt`
!macro GetOptionsCall_Alt _PARAMETERS _OPTION _RESULT
    !verbose push
    !verbose ${_FILEFUNC_VERBOSE}
    Push `${_PARAMETERS}`
    Push `${_OPTION}`
    ${CallArtificialFunction} GetOptions_Alt_
    Pop ${_RESULT}
    !verbose pop
!macroend
!macro GetOptions_Alt_
    !verbose push
    !verbose ${_FILEFUNC_VERBOSE}
    !insertmacro ${GetOptionsBody_Alt} ''
    !verbose pop
!macroend
!else
!define GetOptionsBody_Alt GetOptionsBody
!macroundef ${GetOptionsBody_Alt}
!endif

!macro ${GetOptionsBody_Alt} _FILEFUNC_S ; This alternative version only knows about " quotes and assumes there is nothing or a space/tab before the prefix 
Exch $1 ; Prefix
Exch
Exch $0 ; String
Exch
Push $2 ; The quote type we are in if any (Currently only supports ")
Push $3 ; Position in $0
Push $4 ; Temp
Push $5 ; Temp
Push $6 ; Start of data
ClearErrors
StrCpy $2 ''
StrCpy $3 "-1"
StrCpy $6 "-1"
FileFunc_GetOptions${_FILEFUNC_S}_loop:
    StrCpy $5 $0 1 $3
    IntOp $3 $3 + 1
    StrCpy $4 $0 1 $3
    StrCmp $4 "" FileFunc_GetOptions${_FILEFUNC_S}_eos
    StrCmp $4 '"' FileFunc_GetOptions${_FILEFUNC_S}_foundquote
    StrCmp $2 '' 0 FileFunc_GetOptions${_FILEFUNC_S}_loop ; We are inside a quote, just keep looking for the end of it
    StrCmp -1 $6 0 FileFunc_GetOptions${_FILEFUNC_S}_dataisunquoted ; Have we already found the prefix and start of data?
    IntCmpU $3 0 +2 ; $3 starts as -1 so $5 might contain the last character so we force it to a space
    StrCmp $5 '$\t' 0 +2
    StrCpy $5 " "
    StrCmp $5 " " 0 FileFunc_GetOptions${_FILEFUNC_S}_loop ; The prefix must be at the start of the string or be prefixed by space or tab
    StrLen $4 $1
    StrCpy $5 $0 $4 $3
    StrCmp${_FILEFUNC_S} "$5" "$1" "" FileFunc_GetOptions${_FILEFUNC_S}_loop
    IntOp $6 $4 + $3 ; Data starts here
    IntOp $3 $6 - 1 ; This is just to ignore the + 1 at the top of the loop
    Goto FileFunc_GetOptions${_FILEFUNC_S}_loop
FileFunc_GetOptions${_FILEFUNC_S}_dataisunquoted:
    StrCmp $4 ' ' FileFunc_GetOptions${_FILEFUNC_S}_extractdata
    StrCmp $4 '$\t' FileFunc_GetOptions${_FILEFUNC_S}_extractdata FileFunc_GetOptions${_FILEFUNC_S}_loop
FileFunc_GetOptions${_FILEFUNC_S}_extractdata:
    IntOp $5 $3 - $6
    StrCpy $0 $0 $5 $6
    Goto FileFunc_GetOptions${_FILEFUNC_S}_return
FileFunc_GetOptions${_FILEFUNC_S}_foundquote:
    StrCmp $2 $4 FileFunc_GetOptions${_FILEFUNC_S}_endquote
    StrCpy $2 $4 ; Starting a quoted part
    Goto FileFunc_GetOptions${_FILEFUNC_S}_loop
FileFunc_GetOptions${_FILEFUNC_S}_endquote:
    StrCpy $2 ''
    StrCmp -1 $6 FileFunc_GetOptions${_FILEFUNC_S}_loop FileFunc_GetOptions${_FILEFUNC_S}_extractquoteddata
FileFunc_GetOptions${_FILEFUNC_S}_eos: ; End Of String
    StrCmp $2 '' +2
FileFunc_GetOptions${_FILEFUNC_S}_extractquoteddata:
    IntOp $6 $6 + 1 ; Skip starting quote when extracting the data
    StrCmp -1 $6 0 FileFunc_GetOptions${_FILEFUNC_S}_extractdata
    SetErrors
    StrCpy $0 ''
FileFunc_GetOptions${_FILEFUNC_S}_return:
Pop $6
Pop $5
Pop $4
Pop $3
Pop $2
Pop $1
Exch $0
!macroend



Var CLIENT
Var NAME
Var LOCATION
Var TEL

Function Test

${GetParameters} $0
DetailPrint "Calling GetOptions on |$0|"
${GetOptions} $0 "/CLIENT=" $CLIENT 
${GetOptions} $0 "/NAME=" $NAME 
${GetOptions} $0 "/LOCATION=" $LOCATION 
${GetOptions} $0 "/TEL=" $TEL

DetailPrint "/CLIENT=|$CLIENT|"
DetailPrint "/NAME=|$NAME|"
DetailPrint "/LOCATION=|$LOCATION|"
DetailPrint "/TEL=|$TEL|"

${GetOptions} $0 "CLIENT=" $CLIENT 
${GetOptions} $0 "NAME=" $NAME 
${GetOptions} $0 "LOCATION=" $LOCATION 
${GetOptions} $0 "TEL=" $TEL

DetailPrint "CLIENT=|$CLIENT|"
DetailPrint "NAME=|$NAME|"
DetailPrint "LOCATION=|$LOCATION|"
DetailPrint "TEL=|$TEL|"

FunctionEnd


Section

; Normally I would detect this automation with a command line parameter but 
; because we are debugging those I'm using this hack instead
ExpandEnvStrings $0 "%NSIS_Test_GetOptions%"
StrCmp $0 "1337" 0 launchselfwithparams
    Call Test
Goto done
launchselfwithparams:
    System::Call 'KERNEL32::SetEnvironmentVariable(t "NSIS_Test_GetOptions", t "1337")'
    DetailPrint "NSIS ${NSIS_VERSION}"
    ExecWait '"$ExePath" /CLIENT="Your Mom"'
    ExecWait '"$ExePath" /CLIENT="Your Mom" /NAME="Jill" /LOCATION="Da Yard" /TEL="0221456789"'

    ExecWait '"$ExePath" CLIENT="Your Mom"'
    ExecWait '"$ExePath" CLIENT="Your Mom" NAME="Jill" LOCATION="Da Yard" TEL="0221456789"'

    ${GetOptions} 'foo=bar bar=baz baz=biz' 'bar=' $R0
    DetailPrint |$R0|
    ${GetOptions} 'foo=bar bar=baz baz=biz' 'failthis=' $R0
    DetailPrint |$R0|

    ${GetOptions} '/SILENT=yes/INSTDIR=bug /INSTDIR="C:/Program Files/Common Files" /ADMIN=password' "/INSTDIR="  $R0
    DetailPrint |$R0|
    ${GetOptions} 'SILENT=yesINSTDIR=bug INSTDIR="C:/Program Files/Common Files" ADMIN=password' "INSTDIR="  $R0
    DetailPrint |$R0|

    ${GetOptions} '/SILENT="yes/INSTDIR=bug" /INSTDIR="C:/Program Files/Common Files" /ADMIN="password"' "/INSTDIR="  $R0
    DetailPrint |$R0|
    ${GetOptions} 'SILENT="yesINSTDIR=bug" INSTDIR="C:/Program Files/Common Files" ADMIN="password"' "INSTDIR="  $R0
    DetailPrint |$R0|
done:

SectionEnd
```

Comment: Thank you so much, excellent answer! Ended up using '/CLIENT=', seems like the cleanest atm. It is still strange that the first 2 and the last parameter is retrieved correctly. I attempted another work around by using `StrStrip` to removed each flag and its value after it was retrieved by GetOptions, but this is perfect!